# Issue declaring and then sharing a module with require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around the require.js library, and I'm having an issue that, even if I kind of get the problem, can't seem to resolve it.
I've first created a main.js file :

```
/*
 *
 * Require.js configuration for app
 */
require.config({
 baseUrl: 'assets/js',
 paths:{
    "async": 'vendor/requirejs-plugins/async',
    "jquery": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min",
    "common": "modules/common",
    "jquery-fineuploader": "vendor/jquery-fineuploader/jquery.fineuploader-3.0",
    "google" : "vendor/google/maps/google.init",
    "jqueryui" : "vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min",
    "jqcookie": "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.2/jquery.cookie.min"
},
shim: {
    'jqueryui': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'bootstrap' : {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'common': {
        deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap']
    },
    'google': {
        deps: ['jquery' , 'bootstrap']
    },
    'index':{
        deps: ['jquery' , 'bootstrap']
    },
    'jqcookie': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'jquery-fineuploader': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
 });

 require(["google", "index"], function() {
// Bisous 
 });
```

This file is meant to load the various required files for my app to run.

Then, to stay clean, I created a common.js file, meant to be my common helpers module:

```
//Calling define with module ID, dependency array, and factory function
define(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function () {

return{
    /*
     *
     * All-in-one modal content handler
     *
     */
    modalRefresh : function(redirectUrl, method, data){

        console.log(redirectUrl);
        console.log(method);
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: redirectUrl,
            type: method,
            dataType: "json",
            data: (data) ? data : '',
            success: function( json, textStatus, xhr ) {

                if(json.redirect){
                    modalRefresh(json.redirect, 'GET');
                    return false;
                }

                if(!$('#submitDialog').length){
                    console.log('not found');

                    $('<div class="modal hide fade submitModal" id="submitDialog">' + json.data + '</div>').modal();
                }else{

                    console.log('found');
                    $('#submitDialog').empty().html(json.data);
                }
            },
            error: function( xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}
        });
    }
}
});
```

This file currently only contains what I need to handle my dialog windows, accross the app, even if it's meant to handle further application helpers in a near future.

My problem is I can't seem to access modalRefresh doing the following:

```
define(['jquery','jqueryui', 'bootstrap','common','async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA9NdU3m2ysLvAiK1vjHnba3yQtck-pSFE&sensor=false',"vendor/google/maps/clusterer.min", "tmp/clusteringData"],
function(common){
  common.modalRefresh('test/call','POST', data = {test : 1});  
});
```

I really suspect my module not to be implemented the way it should be, by I can't find where I'm having an issue.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments for the function need to match the arguments in the array that preceded it.

So in other words:

```
define(['jquery','jqueryui', 'bootstrap','common','async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA9NdU3m2ysLvAiK1vjHnba3yQtck-pSFE&sensor=false',"vendor/google/maps/clusterer.min", "tmp/clusteringData"],
function(common) {...
```

should be:

```
define(['jquery','jqueryui', 'bootstrap','common','async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA9NdU3m2ysLvAiK1vjHnba3yQtck-pSFE&sensor=false',"vendor/google/maps/clusterer.min", "tmp/clusteringData"],
function(jquery, jqueryui, boostrap, common) {...
```

Of course, you don't need arguments for imports that you're not using directly (eg. jQuery), so what I do to avoid having to write them is put such imports at the end.  In other words, I would re-write your `define` as:

```
define(['common', 'jquery','jqueryui', 'bootstrap', 'async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA9NdU3m2ysLvAiK1vjHnba3yQtck-pSFE&sensor=false',"vendor/google/maps/clusterer.min", "tmp/clusteringData"],
function(common) {...
```

Comment: Heh, welcome to Require ;-)  Seriously, it's a wonderful library, but it has lots of "make you feel like an idiot" stuff like this, so don't let it intimidate you.  Once you get the hang of using the library, you'll soon appreciate the benefits of using it and it will make you forget all these moments.

Comment: Oh, and just to warn you for what will probably be your next "I'm a moron" moment, if your imports start coming in undefined, even when they shouldn't be, it's almost certainly because you have a circular dependency somewhere.  This could mean you're importing B from file A, but A already imports B, or it could be more complex (A imports C which imports D which imports B).  The xrayquire tool from the Require people can help with this, but usually it's easy to fix once you realize what's going on.

Comment: Now this is what I call super help, really thanks for the tips !